# Fake mysql server to run sql commands on for practice

Tags: sql, testing

I am trying to get better with SQL commands, but I really do not have a database currently set up that I can practice on. Does anyone know of an all-in-one program or an online service that has a database set up and filled with data that I could practice my SQL commands on/in?

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I do not really know of any GOOD online site for doing this.

Google gave me this [site](http://www.sqlcourse.com/cgi-bin/interpreter.cgi) but i tried it out and its really a bit cumbersome and difficult to work with.

I would really suggest that you will find it a LOT easier to install some database like MySQL / SQL Server Express on your machine and try things out.

Installing something like SQL Server Express is really easy. You can just download the db + tools from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/),  a quick install and you will be all set to go

For the sample data, you can always download the [Adventureworks database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/45907).
Step by step details on how to get the AdventureWorks database running with SQL Express are listed [here](http://lwang00.wordpress.com/2007/09/22/install-adventure-works-sample-database-on-the-sql-express/)

Answer (score 1):

Google's your friend

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found this site pretty much helping. 

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics

Although they use mariaDB still same queries.. So no worries.